Postgres query optimization with some joins
Using postgres i have a query that is taking 7 seconds to run,
first, i will give some context ,
i have a table called courses with ~600 rows
create table code:
CREATE TABLE public.courses
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('courses_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  text text NOT NULL,
  formation_type integer NOT NULL,
  status smallint NOT NULL,
  slug character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  course_type integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT courses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
  USING INDEX TABLESPACE data_x01
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
)

a table called
course_prices with 1.5Million rows
create table code:
CREATE TABLE public.course_prices
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('course_prices_id_seq'::regclass),
  course integer NOT NULL,
  institution integer NOT NULL,
  modality integer NOT NULL,
  shift integer NOT NULL,
  price numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
  status smallint NOT NULL,
  duration integer,
  CONSTRAINT course_prices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
  USING INDEX TABLESPACE data_x01
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
)
TABLESPACE data_app01;


CREATE INDEX course_prices_course_idx3
  ON public.course_prices
  USING btree
  (course);

CREATE INDEX course_prices_course_institution_idx
  ON public.course_prices
  USING btree
  (course, institution);

CREATE INDEX idx_course_prices_composite
  ON public.course_prices
  USING btree
  (course, modality);


and a table called course_price_promo
with 1.5Million rows
create table:
-- Table: public.course_price_promo

-- DROP TABLE public.course_price_promo;

CREATE TABLE public.course_price_promo
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('course_price_promo_id_seq'::regclass),
  course_price integer NOT NULL,
  price numeric(10,2),
  begin_date date NOT NULL,
  end_date date NOT NULL,
  status integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT course_price_promo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.course_price_promo
  OWNER TO u_app01;

CREATE INDEX course_price_promo_course_price_begin_date_end_date_price_idx
  ON public.course_price_promo
  USING btree
  (course_price, begin_date, end_date, price);
urse_price_promo_course_price_idx;

CREATE INDEX course_price_promo_course_price_idx
  ON public.course_price_promo
  USING btree
  (course_price);


for now i guess this informations is enough, and the query that im running is:
SELECT 
    "courses"."id",
    "courses"."name",
    "courses"."slug",
    "courses"."course_type",
    "modalities"."name" AS "modality",
    "formation_types"."name" AS "formation_type",
    "course_modality_content"."duration" AS "duration",
    LEAST(MIN(course_prices.price), MIN(course_price_promo.price)) AS min_price
FROM 
    "courses"
INNER JOIN 
    "course_prices" ON "course_prices"."course" = "courses"."id"
INNER JOIN 
    "modalities" ON "course_prices"."modality" = "modalities"."id"
INNER JOIN 
    "formation_types" ON "courses"."formation_type" = "formation_types"."id"
INNER JOIN 
    "course_modality_content" ON "course_modality_content"."course" = "courses"."id"
    AND "course_modality_content"."modality" = "modalities"."id"
LEFT JOIN 
    "course_price_promo" ON "course_price_promo"."course_price" = "course_prices"."id"
    AND "course_price_promo"."status" = '1'
    AND "course_price_promo"."begin_date" <= '2024-06-07'
    AND "course_price_promo"."end_date" >= '2024-06-07'
WHERE 
    "courses"."status" = '1'
    AND "course_prices"."status" = '1'
GROUP BY 
    "courses"."id",
    "modalities"."name",
    "formation_types"."name",
    "course_modality_content"."id"
ORDER BY 
    "courses"."name" ASC
LIMIT 
    12 


the query plan:
"Sort  (cost=718919.76..722498.36 rows=1431440 width=114) (actual time=7363.629..7363.647 rows=502 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: courses.name"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 121kB"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=445126.82..484491.42 rows=1431440 width=114) (actual time=5651.304..7361.781 rows=502 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: courses.id, modalities.name, formation_types.name, course_modality_content.id"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=445126.82..448705.42 rows=1431440 width=114) (actual time=5650.097..6837.582 rows=1668599 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: courses.id, modalities.name, formation_types.name, course_modality_content.id"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 208552kB"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=97433.10..210698.48 rows=1431440 width=114) (actual time=629.076..2497.610 rows=1668599 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: ((course_prices.course = courses.id) AND (course_prices.modality = modalities.id))"
"                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=96962.92..189000.87 rows=1668599 width=20) (actual time=627.370..2002.865 rows=1668599 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (course_prices.id = course_price_promo.course_price)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on course_prices  (cost=0.00..47749.99 rows=1668599 width=18) (actual time=0.004..289.424 rows=1668599 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=75375.36..75375.36 rows=1241885 width=10) (actual time=626.563..626.563 rows=1242761 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 131072  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 4360kB"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on course_price_promo  (cost=0.00..75375.36 rows=1241885 width=10) (actual time=54.529..438.553 rows=1242761 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((begin_date <= '2024-06-07'::date) AND (end_date >= '2024-06-07'::date))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 425838"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=459.93..459.93 rows=683 width=114) (actual time=1.693..1.693 rows=681 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 108kB"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=190.91..459.93 rows=683 width=114) (actual time=0.591..1.451 rows=681 loops=1)"
"                                Hash Cond: (course_modality_content.modality = modalities.id)"
"                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=189.86..449.49 rows=683 width=103) (actual time=0.578..1.287 rows=681 loops=1)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (courses.id = course_modality_content.course)"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.18..250.71 rows=654 width=81) (actual time=0.019..0.579 rows=654 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (courses.formation_type = formation_types.id)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on courses  (cost=0.00..240.54 rows=654 width=74) (actual time=0.001..0.244 rows=654 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=1.08..1.08 rows=8 width=15) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on formation_types  (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=8 width=15) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=179.97..179.97 rows=697 width=22) (actual time=0.550..0.550 rows=685 loops=1)"
"                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 46kB"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on course_modality_content  (cost=0.00..179.97 rows=697 width=22) (actual time=0.002..0.440 rows=685 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=1.02..1.02 rows=2 width=11) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on modalities  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=11) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=2 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 1.652 ms"
"Execution time: 7405.942 ms"


what i realized is that, when i increase work_mem to 500MB, the query plan, instead of using GroupAggregate, uses the HashAggregate, and the execution time decreases to 3.5s, but i dont really know the consequences of it.
some things I wanted to know are,
1- my joins are all generating a Seq Scan. Are there any index changes I could make to generate an Index Scan, or in this situation would it not make sense?
2- "Are there any changes to the query that could be made to improve performance?"
(Edit1)
Plan with buffers:
"Limit  (cost=479946.05..479946.08 rows=12 width=114) (actual time=7439.660..7439.662 rows=12 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=23754 read=58053, temp read=50382 written=50352"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=479946.05..483021.24 rows=1230076 width=114) (actual time=7439.653..7439.654 rows=12 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: courses.name"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=23754 read=58053, temp read=50382 written=50352"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=417919.70..451746.79 rows=1230076 width=114) (actual time=5744.841..7438.856 rows=502 loops=1)"
"              Group Key: courses.id, modalities.name, formation_types.name, course_modality_content.id"
"              Buffers: shared hit=23754 read=58053, temp read=50382 written=50352"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=417919.70..420994.89 rows=1230076 width=114) (actual time=5743.647..6909.473 rows=1668599 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: courses.id, modalities.name, formation_types.name, course_modality_content.id"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 208552kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=23754 read=58053, temp read=50382 written=50352"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=101602.85..217815.07 rows=1230076 width=114) (actual time=708.412..2671.843 rows=1668599 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((course_prices.course = courses.id) AND (course_prices.modality = modalities.id))"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=23754 read=58053, temp read=12236 written=12206"
"                          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=101136.48..197345.93 rows=1668599 width=20) (actual time=706.855..2158.778 rows=1668599 loops=1)"
"                                Hash Cond: (course_prices.id = course_price_promo.course_price)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=23345 read=58053, temp read=12236 written=12206"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on course_prices  (cost=0.00..51921.49 rows=1668599 width=18) (actual time=0.004..350.854 rows=1668599 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (status = '1'::smallint)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=16185 read=14879"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=79548.92..79548.92 rows=1241885 width=10) (actual time=706.346..706.346 rows=1242761 loops=1)"
"                                      Buckets: 131072  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 4360kB"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=7160 read=43174, temp written=4545"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on course_price_promo  (cost=0.00..79548.92 rows=1241885 width=10) (actual time=55.241..511.046 rows=1242761 loops=1)"
"                                            Filter: ((begin_date <= '2024-06-07'::date) AND (end_date >= '2024-06-07'::date) AND (status = 1))"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 425838"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=7160 read=43174"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=457.56..457.56 rows=587 width=114) (actual time=1.549..1.549 rows=587 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 94kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=409"
"                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=190.91..457.56 rows=587 width=114) (actual time=0.609..1.375 rows=587 loops=1)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (course_modality_content.modality = modalities.id)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=409"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=189.86..448.44 rows=587 width=103) (actual time=0.597..1.242 rows=587 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (courses.id = course_modality_content.course)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=408"
"                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.18..251.08 rows=562 width=81) (actual time=0.016..0.533 rows=562 loops=1)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: (courses.formation_type = formation_types.id)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=235"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on courses  (cost=0.00..242.18 rows=562 width=74) (actual time=0.003..0.379 rows=562 loops=1)"
"                                                        Filter: (status = '1'::smallint)"
"                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 92"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=234"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1.08..1.08 rows=8 width=15) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on formation_types  (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=8 width=15) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=179.97..179.97 rows=697 width=22) (actual time=0.575..0.575 rows=685 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 46kB"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=173"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on course_modality_content  (cost=0.00..179.97 rows=697 width=22) (actual time=0.003..0.484 rows=685 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=173"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=1.02..1.02 rows=2 width=11) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on modalities  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=11) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1"
"Planning time: 2.410 ms"
"Execution time: 7481.816 ms"



You have 1.5 Million prices for 600 courses?

@topsail each course_price row is for combination of a active course, institution (12k rows) and modality (2rows),

Add the execution plan with explain (analyze, buffers) select... and how was that increase of memory that you mention?

@PepeNO I added the execution plan with buffers on the post, i inscreased the work_mem by running  SET work_mem = "500MB"

I'm under the impression that you have a bug in your data model. I don't understand how you can have 1.5 million prices for just 600 courses, and on top of that another 1.5 million promo prices for the same courses. And that for just a few days since 75% of these prices are valid for just 2024-06-07. Thousands of different prices per course per day doesn't make sense to me. I would first check and double check this data model.

Add to that that after checking all these millions of prices you are limiting to 12 ... which seems an awful lot data to work through for only 12 records that are more or less arbitrary (top 12 by name of course) (-- although to be honest we have a query just like that I'm dealing with at my work so I also need to take my own advice and fix it up!).
